# On Updating XCode 6.3.2 Simulators vanished

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6.3

On updating XCode6.3.2 all my simulators vanished. now simulators aren't being listed any more to run app.

[image]

Further more I tried adding simulators from Window->Devices, its not working as well, its just keep spinning and XCode is hanging on it

Although its pretty strange Preferences->Downloads is showing all simulators as installed, on clicking "Check and install Now" returns No updates

[image]

any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three steps to add additional simulators

1.Just run the simulator
2.Hardware ----> Device---> Manage Device.
3.A popup will open, in that screen bottom left corner you will find "+" use + for adding new simulators for different ios versions

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is listed here: https://openradar.appspot.com/21052114

Basically: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` then reboot

Answer (score 0):

Xcode -> preferences -> downloads (if reset Xcode does not help)

Comment: I have updated question, Downloads shows all simulators as installed. From where I can reset XCode?

Comment: Quit it and launch again. If it does not work restart mac, if it does not work reinstall Xcode. (there must be some tricky solution, but it will take more time I guess)